# is there an error in “The generation of the implicitly-defined copy constructor is deprecated if T has a user-defined destructor”

Tags: c++, c++11

I read this sentence in  [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#:%7E:text=The%20generation%20of%20the%20implicitly%2Ddefined%20copy%20constructor%20is%20deprecated%20if%20T%20has%20a%20user%2Ddefined%20destructor).It says **The generation of the implicitly-defined copy constructor is deprecated if T has a user-defined destructor**. Maybe there is an error.

I test in a code：

First I define destructor, copy/move constructor and copy/move assignment operator.

```
#include <iostream>
struct B {
    B() { std::cout << "B()" << std::endl; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "~B()" << std::endl; }

    B(const B&) { std::cout << "B(const B&)" << std::endl; }
    B& operator=(const B&) { std::cout << "B& operator=(const B&)" << std::endl; return *this; }

    B(B&&) { std::cout << "B(B&&)" << std::endl; }
    B& operator=(B&&) { std::cout << "B& operator=(B&&)" << std::endl; return *this; }
};
int main()
{
    B b1{};
    B b2{b1}; //copy constructor
    return 0;
}
```

console print :

```
B()
B(const B&)
~B()
~B()
```

Second I only define move constructor and move assignment operator. The copy constructor will be implicitly-declared deleted.

```
#include <iostream>
struct B {
    B() { std::cout << "B()" << std::endl; }
    //~B() { std::cout << "~B()" << std::endl; }

    // B(const B&) { std::cout << "B(const B&)" << std::endl; }
    // B& operator=(const B&) { std::cout << "B& operator=(const B&)" << std::endl; return *this; }

    B(B&&) { std::cout << "B(B&&)" << std::endl; }
    B& operator=(B&&) { std::cout << "B& operator=(B&&)" << std::endl; return *this; }
};
int main()
{
    B b1{};
    B b2{b1}; //compile error
    return 0;
}
```

The test code will compile error. I think this is the correct, because copy constructor is deleted.

Finally, I only define destructor

```
#include <iostream>
struct B {
    B() { std::cout << "B()" << std::endl; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "~B()" << std::endl; }

    // B(const B&) { std::cout << "B(const B&)" << std::endl; }
    // B& operator=(const B&) { std::cout << "B& operator=(const B&)" << std::endl; return *this; }

    // B(B&&) { std::cout << "B(B&&)" << std::endl; }
    // B& operator=(B&&) { std::cout << "B& operator=(B&&)" << std::endl; return *this; }
};
int main()
{
    B b1{};
    B b2{b1};
    return 0;
}
```

**The generation of the implicitly-defined copy constructor is deprecated if T has a user-defined destructor**. so I think the test code will compile error, but it's correct. WHY???

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean compilation error. Thing is, there might be a potential bug in generated code if you have default copy constructor and non-no-operation user-defined destructor.

Comment: It's deprecated so may be removed in a future version of the standard but currently the most you'll get is a warning

Comment: clang does raise a warning: https://godbolt.org/z/q7rbG9zsG

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks, gcc doesn't give me a warning, it makes me confused

Comment: If you follow rule of zero/three/five you will get rid of that warning.

Comment: If you have a destructor that manages resources (and not just display a message), you *probably* also have to manage those resources in the copy constructor. So only having one of them is potentially an error,